# Return the correct Observable<Response> and not the Promise itself

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm making an HTTP request interceptor and I'm overriding the `Http` module `get` method so I can automatically add a JWT token to the headers.

I've tried it with the following code, but I get the following error when returning from the method:

> Type `Promise<Observable<Response>>` is not assignable to type `Observable<Response>`.

Even when I try to return it within a `then()` it gives me the same error.

How can I get the correct `Observable<Response>` and return it?

```
// ...

@Injectable()
export class AdalHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.getWithAdal(url, options); // <-- ERROR HERE
  }

  private getWithAdal(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Promise<Observable<Response>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authenticate((authResponse) => {
        if (!options) {
          options = { headers: new Headers() };
        }

        options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authResponse.accessToken);

        resolve(super.get(url, options));
      }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: What is this.authenticate?

Comment: can you use `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get method should return Observable. It calls getWithAdal method and returns immediately the object returned by getWithAdal. So getWithAdal should also return Observable.

Use Observable.fromPromise to convert promise to Observable, change signature of getWithAdal method to return Observable

```
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      return this.getWithAdal(url, options); // <-- ERROR HERE
    }

    private getWithAdal(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // just make it simpler for the example.... keep your code here as is
        let options = {headers: new Headers()};
        options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ');
        resolve(super.get(url, options));
      }));
    }
```